# ItemListener does not work

Tags: java, swing

why does my combo box doesn't perform the things I have declared in the ItemListener? When I click an item inside the combo box, the program hangs I need to close the entire BlueJ. Please take a look what is wrong in my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HulaHoops {

private Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[]args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new HulaHoops();
        }
    });
}

public HulaHoops() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String choices[] = {"Shoes","Comb","Ball"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(choices);
    combo.setBackground(Color.gray);
    combo.setForeground(Color.red);
    panel.add(combo);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,100);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener () {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            String item = (String)e.getItem();
            if (e.getStateChange () == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose " +item);
                    if (item == "Shoes")
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
                        int bilang = inp.nextInt();
                        int total = bilang * 99;
                        String order = bilang + " " + "Shoes " + "     " + total;
                        System.out.print("" + order);
                    }

                    else if (item == "Comb")
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
                        int bilang = inp.nextInt();
                        int total1 = bilang * 99;
                        String order1 = bilang + " " + "Comb " + "     " + total1;
                        System.out.print("" + order1);
                    }

                    else if (item == "Ball")
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
                        int bilang = inp.nextInt();
                        int total2 = bilang * 99;
                        String order2 = bilang + " " + "Ball " + "     " + total2;
                        System.out.print("" + order2);
                    }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: And always don't compare strings using ==, instead use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic mistake that you are doing is comparing the two String objects using `==` operator. 
You should use the following conditions instead:

```
if (item .equals("Shoes"))
if (item .equals("Comb"))
if (item .equals("Ball"))
```

As a short demo of JOptionPane.. I am putting here the changed version of your code...I hope it will help you to understand how to handle such situation properly...

```
    //combo box, the program hangs I need to close the entire BlueJ. Please take a look what is wrong in my code
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HulaHoops  {

private Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[]args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new HulaHoops();
        }
    });
}

public HulaHoops() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String choices[] = {"Shoes","Comb","Ball"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(choices);
    combo.setBackground(Color.gray);
    combo.setForeground(Color.red);
    panel.add(combo);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,100);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener () {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            String item = (String)e.getItem();
            if (e.getStateChange () == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose " +item);
                    if (item.equals("Comb"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of comb"); 
            System.out.println(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        int total = bilang * 99;
                        String order = bilang + " " + "Shoes " + "     " + total;
                        System.out.print("" + order);
                    }


            }
    }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that one but it still hangs up after I select an item in the combo box

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya:It is not the good choice to block EDT using Scanner .. but as a resolution to solve ur GUI hanging problem what I suggest you is that: after you select some item in combobox click on the Console via which you are running java program and there input the value and then press enter...It is executing at my side.. Now coming to standard way of handling this Requirement, You can use JOptionPane.inputDialog(...) as suggested by Reimeus .. or any other GUI on ur main frame itself like TextField .. To take Input from user..when the Combobox state is changed..

Comment: thank you very much now I understand why I shouldn't insert a `Scanner` in a Swing application :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are blocking the `EDT` calling `Scanner#nextInt` waiting for input from `System.in` in your `ItemListener`:

```
int bilang = inp.nextInt();
```

Don't use `Scanner` to read user input in Swing applications. This will only block the `EDT` until the data is provided in the console window. There are a number of ways to read the input such as using `JOptionPane#showInputDialog`. For more on this option see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

---

Aside from this, use `.equals` when comparing `String` content rather than the `==` operator. The latter compares `Object` references.

Comment: Then what is the alternative code for the `Scanner` Sir? How should I input quantities then?

Comment: That depends on how you want to input the data. I've given you a link for the `JOptionPane`. Although you _may_ wish to have a fixed `JTextField` for input rather than having a popup dialog.